# Error handling - global error catalog?

Tags: c#

Back when I was writing C code I might have used global #defines for error numbers.  I can't do that in C#.  I could use an error class, but I'd have to pass it around.  Is it really such a serious faux pas to have a global error catalog class?  A class containing, for example, a dictionary of errors and messages?  How could it be handled better?

Ok, I could have been clearer... sorry.

Let's say I am accessing a database, or several databases, in different classes.  If I get an error accessing a database I want to display an error message of some sort, but I don't necessarily want to display the system generated error message - I have my own error catalog that I want to use.  Let's say I have a standard "Database Access Error" string that I want to show, but I want to add the database name and table.  I could achieve that with a couple of #defines in C.  How should I handle that with c# - a singleton class globally accessible that contains a dictionary?  Is that a bad thing?

Comment: What are you after, exactly? Are you talking about error codes to return from a C# console application you are writing? Or are you talking about handling errors internal to your application?

Comment: `I could use an error class, but I'd have to pass it around` What does this mean??

Comment: Make the error lookup static?

Comment: I see your answer, but I don't think it works for me. It's not the programmers working on the project I'm concerned about. I want to present users with meaningful, consistent error or warning messages. I'd like those messages to exist in a message catalog on disk that I use to populate a catalog in memory. I'm thinking of a singleton that acts as a message server - it would be populated from the disk catalog when the application starts.  The errors won't always be exceptions - I could throw exceptions for them I suppose.  They could just be warning messages - "Stock X getting low" for example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define a custom dictionary with code and message that will work for you, but it's not a good practice. If your code become more and more larger, giving a meaningful name  to your exception is better than code. Think when there are more than one person work on the some project if you use a customclass it will be more easier as intellisense will come in help.

In c# it works in  a different way you  can use a custom exception class for each C code you have defined  something like this

```
using System;

public class EmployeeListNotFoundException: Exception
{
    int _codeException; 
    public EmployeeListNotFoundException()
    {

    }

    public EmployeeListNotFoundException(string message,int codeException)
        : base(message)
    {
                  _codeException=codeException; 
    }

    public EmployeeListNotFoundException(string message, Exception inner)
        : base(message, inner)
    {

    }
   public int CodeException{get {return _codeException;} }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If its bad or not depends on the size of the codebase, the type of the application or program and the architecture. You could see an architecture as a set of constraints that enforces a certain 'style' to the code. If the architecture dictates that having stuff at global scope is bad then you should avoid it. If you anyway want to keep the error code information on a global scope, I would suggest wrapping your readonly  dictionary in a singleton.